# "failure windows configuration reverting changes do not turn off your computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I'm on Windows  7, I can't get past this screen no matter what I do, I've tried everything I could but it's just stuck at that point.

What are my options to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you just wait a while?

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows 7 installation disc and select "System Recovery Options", then "System Restore" and the latest restore point before failure date.

If there are no restore points you should use "in-place upgrade" to recover Windows 7 to a good state - run "setup.exe" from installation media and select "Install" + "Go online to obtain the latest updates" + "Upgrade" options.